# why am i getting Insufficient Privileges on contacts from my customer community user?

Tags: customer-community, sharing-rule

I have created a customer community and granted sharing rules to the customer user but he cant seem to access the contact entity no matter what.
If i change the wide organisation set to public he can see it, but the sharing rules don't seem to be enough, anyone knows why.

So the question is:
why am i getting Insufficient Privileges on contacts from my customer community user?

Comment: Which profile are these on - customer community or customer community plus?

Comment: @DaveHumm -  customer community

Comment: In that case sharing rules do not work for them. It is sharing sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Customer Community users it is not possible to use Sharing Rules, these are only available to users with a Customer Community Plus licence type.

Instead you need to create Sharing Sets - these are setup as follows:

Setup->Build>Customise>Commmunities>Community Settings - then select Sharing sets and create a sharing set based on sharing a Contact to a community user, e.g. if the user should see the other contacts for that account then use

```
User:Contact.Account = Account:Id
```

And set to Read only or Read/Write as appropriate. This will require the OWD to be setup with Contact as Private for external users.

Example pic for a custom object where I needed to use Case as the junction.

[image]